# Need help removing deny permissions while granting Users full control

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I appreciate any help that can be given on this issue. So, to keep things simple lets just say I have a 3rd party program and in order for it to work properly now, I have to modify a folder so Users have Full Control and I also have to remove the Deny permissions that is present for Users. Doing this manually is a pain as there are about 5 folders that have to be modified, and multiple computers per location.

I currently use the following in my .bat files to grant users or domain users full control.
**Icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\testbatfiles" /grant:r "Users":(OI)(CI)F**

I read that I can use /remove:d to remove deny permissions and their example had /remove:d /grant:r thus, I modify my bat file to be this,

**Icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\testbatfiles" /remove:d /grant:r "Users":(OI)(CI)F** 
However, if I try to run this bat file with this new /remove:d it does not work. I noticed that if I just keep the original /grant:r line and add a new Icacls line with /remove:d that seems to work.

My question is, can I remove deny permissions while granting users rights in the same command? If so, how? 
The computers here at our branches are Windows 10 32bit.

Thanks,
Sean R

Comment: Try this: Icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\testbatfiles" /remove:d "Users":(OI)(CI)F /grant:r "Users":(OI)(CI)F

Comment: I tried that way, and Icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\testbatfiles" /grant:r "Users":(OI)(CI)F /remove:d "Users":(OI)(CI)F - Neither of them work. The batch file runs but nothing is processed. I verified by checking the folder permissions.

Comment: I don't think they can be combined. If I run /remove:d on another line it works fine. I will just add the extra leg work into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your one-liner.

`icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\testbatfiles" /remove:d "Users" /grant:r "Users":(OI)(CI)F /T`

I ran and verified this command on my Windows 8 machine.

I removed the deny permissions first with `/remove:d "Users"`.  The remove switch does not require the `(OI)(CI)` parameters.  It simply removes all denied permissions for that user.

Then I processed the `/grant:r "Users:(OI)(CI)F /T` to give the user full control.  The `/T` passes those permissions to all files and directories in the subfolders.  You can remove that if you don't want the permissions to go that far.

This worked on a folder of mine containing over 11,000 files and directories.  I verified the setting took effect on a few dozen in various locations and they were all changed accordingly.

Comment: Oh, well I was close with my original post. It seems from your syntax. I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Works like a charm. Appreciate the help!